# google.cloud.container_v1.types.Cluster: using node_pools

Tags: python, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I need to create a cluster using GKECreateClusterOperator in airflow 2.0.1. I need to create this cluster with a node pool other than the default. This operator receives an object of type google.cloud.container_v1.types.Cluster. In the [google_cloud_container version documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/container/latest/container_v1/types.html#google.cloud.container_v1.types.Cluster) it says that the initial_node_count parameter of the Cluster object cannot be used at the same time as the node_pools parameter. But an error occurs if initial_node_count is not present. Airflow 2.0.1 uses google-cloud-container version 1.0.1, but I couldn't find the documentation for that version

Here the the code

```
from google.cloud.container_v1.types import (
    Cluster,
    ClusterAutoscaling,
    VerticalPodAutoscaling,
    ResourceLimit,
    NodeConfig,
    AutoprovisioningNodePoolDefaults,
    NodePool,
    NodePoolAutoscaling
)

def get_cluster_config():
    node_pool_config = NodeConfig(oauth_scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

    node_pool_auto_scaling = NodePoolAutoscaling(
        enabled=True,
        min_node_count=0,
        max_node_count=11,
        autoprovisioned=False
    )

    node_pool = NodePool(
        name="extraction-pool",
        config=node_pool_config,
        initial_node_count=1,
        autoscaling=node_pool_auto_scaling

    )

    cpu = ResourceLimit(resource_type="cpu", maximum=20, minimum=1)
    memory = ResourceLimit(resource_type="memory", maximum=80, minimum=4)

    cluster_auto_scaling = ClusterAutoscaling(
        resource_limits=[cpu, memory]
    )

    cluster_config = Cluster(
        name="extraction-cluster",
        location="southamerica-east1-a",
        node_pools=[node_pool],
        autoscaling=cluster_auto_scaling
    )

    return cluster_config
```

Comment: You can find the docs for 1.0.1 [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/container/1.0.1/index.html).

Comment: Also, can you include your full script, I'm not sure I follow what you've currently created, looks like you're retrieving a context and not actually creating a cluster. But I may be mistaken.

Comment: I tested the GKE cluster configuration with a DAG file. While importing the DAG file into Composer, I got the following error  `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Operator has incorrect or missing input.` To isolate the issue, I tried to create a standalone GKE cluster with the configuration provided and it was successful. So, the problem lies with the GKECreateClusterOperator and the initial_node_count parameter. Please create a [Github issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Aprovider%3AGoogle) in the Airflow repository explaining the problem.